# Arithmetic Mean app that reads values every button click

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

I want to make an app to calculate arithmetic mean, but the person will put values and click a button and the app will be adding all the values and counting the number of clicks, and when another button is clicked it will take the all added values and divide by the number of clicks.
But I don't know how to make it work.

```
package com.example.arithmeticmean;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView result;
    EditText values;
    Button isrt_btn, calc_btn;
    String op, rs;
    Double sum, r;
    Integer count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        result = findViewById(R.id.result);
        values = findViewById(R.id.values);
        isrt_btn = findViewById(R.id.isrt_btn);
        isrt_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count++;
                op = values.getText().toString();
                sum = sum + Double.parseDouble(op);
                result.setText(op + values);

            }
        });
        calc_btn = findViewById(R.id.calc_btn);
        calc_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                r = sum/count;
                rs = Double.toString(r);
                result.setText(rs);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

When I click the Insert Button the app crashes.

Comment: Which error you are getting is It parsing issue from String to double ?  ```sum = sum + Double.parseDouble(op);```  or something else ?

Comment: The problem is that the app is not taking the input values instead when I click the button the app just crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing mistake on this line

```
result.setText(op + values)
```

values is an edittext variable. So, look at it.
Hope it helps! :)